# Evaluating a sum(could be decomposed into partial sum)

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if somebody could provide help with evaluating the following sum?[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Using  [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),

$$\frac2{(2n-1)2n(2n+1)}=\frac A{2n}+\frac B{2n-1}+\frac C{2n+1}$$

Multiply either sides by $(2n-1)2n(2n+1)$ and compare the coefficients of the different powers of $n$ to find $A,B,C$

---

Alternatively,
$$\frac2{(2n-1)2n(2n+1)}=2\cdot\frac{4n^2-(2n-1)(2n+1)}{(2n-1)2n(2n+1)}=\frac{4n}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}-\frac1n$$

Again, $$\frac{4n}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac{2n+1+(2n-1)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac1{2n-1}+\frac1{2n+1}$$

$$\implies\frac2{(2n-1)2n(2n+1)}=\frac1{2n-1}+\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1n $$

Comment: I did. See the right side of the equivalence.

Comment: @user118837, please find the editer version

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to sum from n=1 to infinity (I think I saw the initial post a couple of days ago). You went to partial fractions and this is fine. So, now you must compute the value of S1 + S2 - S3 (I use your and Lab's writing). Individually, each sum diverges but rewrite
S1 + S2 - S3 as T1 + T2
using
T1 = (S1 - S3 /2) and T2 = (S2 - S3 /2)
You will need to show that T1 = -1 + log(2) and T2 = log(2)